# Is Clux Wallet Genuine? I am asked to add funds to my Clux Wallet in order tp generate a private key

Tags: wallet, private-key, fraud

I am new to crypto trading. My crypto trader refused to send the earnings to Binance or WazirX saying there are issues with these wallets on their side. And deposited my funds in a crypto wallet called Clux Wallet. Now to withdraw or send the money in that wallet, I am being askes to add more money to my wallet to generate a private key. Is clux wallet genuine?